# How should I handle ranting in answers?

Tags: discussion, editing, answers, ranting

I [removed a rant](https://superuser.com/posts/397974/revisions) from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/397974/73918).  Is this the right thing to do or should I take some other action?

Comment: seems like it should be handled like taglines and signatures and just removed.

Comment: Note that some users are just stupid and think *their* rants are actually interesting. They're not. And in case you're not sure, you can always ask whether to do it / whether it was a good edit on chat.

Comment: @DanielBeck which chatroom is best for asking questions about good/bad edits?

Comment: @JeremyW Just ask in Root Access, the general room for this site. There are usually a few moderators and experienced users in there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's absolutely fine to do. Here's what's wrong with rants:

- They distract from the actual content of a post
- They offer a possibility for off-topic discussion and flamewars.
- They make you look unprofessional.
- In the long run, they make **us** – as a site – look unprofessional.

We don't want that. So, if you can, always remove rants. [**Be nice**](https://superuser.com/faq#etiquette).

In this case, the original answer was a pretty severe example, and should have probably been deleted. Yes, I know it's a self-answer, but maybe the OP can phrase it a bit more elegantly.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for cleaning up the cruft. What you did was right, however, if it descends into a rollback/edit war, just flag them rather than engaging into a war.